# Is it possible to start audio play when app is in the background in iOS?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to start audio play when app is in the background? 
When my app is in the background , it calls the method to play the sound but AvAudioPlayer doesnt play.

Ive gone through various links on the web regarding this but all I could find is how to continue playing audio when app goes in the background. So does this mean we can't start the audio play in the background?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: are you sure the method is called? if yes, you might need to change your audiosession and check for remotecontrols

Comment: yes, the method is being called. I checked using breakpoints. And I've added this as well in my code but it doesnt work  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

Comment: I play music in the background, too. The only difference I see right now, is that I also set my class as first responder. Did you set your "run in background" key in the plist? This might help: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html

Comment: I did all that already. audioPlayer.isPlaying property returns 0 in the NSlog after calling [audioPlayer play] method.

Comment: in my case it works, you cannot start recording but you can play record also if the app is not in foreground.